# Do your skill points increase for picking locks in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

Is picking locks supposed to increase one of your skill tree points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope**, picking locks does not provide any experience to any of the trees (Power, Survivor, or Agility). It's not a skill you can improve (like Skyrim for example) and not a skill that you level up.